# Expected end of statement error with FindFirst and findNext

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following code is meant to compare a field value PURE_QP1 of a recordset to another field value PURE_QP1 of another second set. But i am getting end of statement expected error. My knowledge of Access vba is admittedly low.
The code is meant to first check if the productcode is present in recordset rst.
if it is, then it checks if it is compliant by finding its PURE_QP1 (which coud be more than 1) in another table. the condition for compliance is such that all its QP1s must be found in the table.

```vb
Dim db   As DAO.Database
Dim rst  As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset

If Nz(Me!Combo_Product_number) <> "" Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Q_compliant_FCM_EU", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("T_DOSSIER_FPL", dbOpenDynaset)


    Do While Not rst.EOF
        If rst.Fields("PRODUCT_CODE") = Me!Combo_Product_number Then
            rst1.FindFirst "[PURE_QP1] = '"rst.Fields("PURE_QP1")"'"

            If rst.NoMatch Then
                MsgBox ("Product code is NOT compliant to FPL")
                Exit Sub
            End If

            rst1.FindNext"[PURE_QP1] = '"rst.Fields("PURE_QP1")"'"

   Loop
   MsgBox ("Product code is compliant to FPL")

Else
   MsgBox ("Product is not available in FCM_EU")
End If



End If

End Sub
```

Expected end of staement error is showing in

```vb
rst1.FindFirst "[PURE_QP1] = '"rst.Fields("PURE_QP1")"'"
```

and

```vb
rst1.FindNext"[PURE_QP1] = '"rst.Fields("PURE_QP1")"'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `End If` just before `End Sub`. That `End If` should go above `Loop` command to close the `If rst.Fields("PRODUCT_CODE") = Me!Combo_Product_number Then` if block.

Also your code regarding rst1 is wrong.

```
rst1.FindFirst "[PURE_QP1] = '"rst.Fields("PURE_QP1")"'"
```

should be

```
rst1.FindFirst "[PURE_QP1] = '" & rst.Fields("PURE_QP1") & "'"
```

the **&** sign to join strings are missing in your code.

PS: Have no idea what your code supposed to do, because your find first and find next logic seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I have made the corrections as you have pointed out. I changed the findnext....blablabla to rst1.movenext      and delete the "else" stament for simplicity sake but if i click the button that has the vba, the whola access engine hangs. wat could be the reason for this new problem. ?

Comment: Add here how the code looks like now. It does not make sense to me what you have up there.

Comment: Please how do i add the code in the comment section because it is comlaining of too long charaxcter. you know it is not a new post